# Is there a TypeScript counterpart to React PropTypes.instanceOf()?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-proptypes

How can I declare that a prop is an instance of a specific React component (e.g. Message) with TypeScript?

When using Typechecking with PropTypes I would write the following:

```
MyComponent.propTypes = {
  optionalMessage: PropTypes.instanceOf(Message),
}
```

Is this type of checking also achievable with TypeScript?

```
type Props = {
  optionalMessage: ...
}
```

MyComponent and Message are both Functional Components. For instance:

```
import React from "react";

const Message = () => {
  return (
    <p>My Message</p>
  );
};

export default Message;
```

Comment: Have you tried: `type Props = { optionalMessage: Message; }` ?

Comment: @Yoshi This throws the following Error:
TS2749: 'Message' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Message'

If I try 'typeof Message' it comes up with:
TS2322: Type 'Element' is not assignable to type '(props: Props) => JSX.Element'.

Comment: Can you explain what `Message` is? A type or a component?

Comment: Message is a functional React component.

Comment: Ah! Then you probably/might want something like: `type Props = { optionalMessage: ComponentType<typeof Message>; }`

Comment: @Yoshi TS2322: Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<(props: Props) => Element> | undefined'. It does also not work with `type Props = { optionalMessage: FunctionComponent<typeof Message>; }`

Answer (score 2):

In TypeScript exists the type `InstanceType` [you can find documentation here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype)

It will return the instance type of the constructor function

Comment: If I write `type Props = { optionalMessage: InstanceType<typeof Message>; }` it throws me the following error:
TS2344: Type '(props: Props) => JSX.Element' does not satisfy the constraint 'abstract new (...args: any) => any'

Could you help me with that?

Comment: Well, `Message`, in your case, is a functional component so, maybe, in your case what you need is `type Props = { optionalMessage: typeOf Message; }` or `type Props = { optionalMessage: ReturnType<Message>; }`